# Attach a rigid body system to a rigged mesh (earring)

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I made a simple earring for my character : the earring is a low-poly torus set as Active in the rigid body settings, I also have a cube as the passive rigid body, and finally an empty used for the Hinge rigid body constraint between the cube and the earring.

[image]

I simply need to attach this system to the rig of my character. In fact, the passive body is located at the bottom of the character's ear. So I need this system to follow the head bone here, keeping the offset between the rigid bodies and the bone of course.

I can make the passive rigid body and the empty follow the character's head movements, but for **the earring, either it won't follow, or the rigid body simulation is canceled**.

It is probably very easy to achieve, but I can't figure it out.

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe [Animated box](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/physics/rigid_body/tips.html?highlight=animated%20checkbox).

Comment: @tetii It is already checked on the passive body, sry I forgot to mention that. It indeed allows the Earring to follow the passive location, but the simulation isn't correct (inertia is not calculated). Then, if the passive "animatable" body is set to follow the rig movements, then the earring stops following the passive body...

Comment: Could you share a file [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?  I want to confirm the problem.

Comment: At a guess I'd say you're looking for an 'automatic' solution. If all else fails you might like to try as I do, not wrestle with the physics engine.  Have a duplicate ring given cloth physics and pinned at the top 20 degrees. Keyframe the original (solid ring) to track the cloth ring's motions.
See example -

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_PgzuRUHXQaNMH1D0I?e=SvLiH4